Trying to interact with a deployed program on devnet. Unsure how to pass program Id
Using @coral-xyz/anchor v0.30.1 the exported Program class no longer accepts programId as the second parameter. I can only find references of older versions of this which does accept programID. Is there a new way you have to pass the program id so you can interact with the deployed program?
old:
  const program = new Program<MintNft>(
      IDL as MintNft,
      programId,
      provider
  );

new:
  const program = new Program<MintNft>(
      IDL as MintNft,
      provider
  );

docs for Program https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/Program.html#programId
thanks!

So it doesn't look like it is needed anymore. I was able to successfully interact with a deployed program. I think the issue I was having before was unrelated to not having the program id.
